# Using Regex to with fixed character count and delimiters

Tags: regex

So I have a case where i want to get every 5 character code which is delimited by /
Problem is the codes itself can contain the delimiter so I can't use something like `([^\/]+)`

E.g.

- `07070` should give me `07070`
- `07070/01010` should give me `07070 01010`
- `0/0/0/BBBBB` should give me `0/0/0 BBBBB`
- `AAAAA/BBBBB/CCCCC` should give me `AAAAA BBBBB CCCCCC`

Any ideas how i can use a regex to achieve this?

Comment: Your middle examples aren't "delimited" by `/` (at least not *only* `/`).

Comment: Please clarify your examples with " * "  ? Is this a literal * character or something else. How do we know the code is "70707" and not "707**"?

Comment: My bad the formatting got cut off

Comment: Do check again!

Answer (score 0):

```
use : (?<yourToken>.{5})\/?
```

yourToken : is the name of match group you want.
while iterating on your code get match group with name `yourToken`

Note that : 07/01010 will get 07/01 only

in java :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<yourToken>.{5})\\/?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("AAAAA/BBBBB/CCCCC");
while (matcher.find()){
  System.out.println(matcher.group("yourToken"));
}
```

check here:
https://regex101.com/r/4vBAL9/1

Answer (score 0):

Since you know your codes are always 5 chars followed by a delimiting `/` you can just count 5 chars:

```
(.{5})(\/?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/paLxPv/1

Your codes will be in `\1`

Answer (score 0):

- Find: `/(?=[^/]{5}(?:/| |$))`
- Replace:       # (a space)

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/1jUffc/1)